# mdadm scheduled check

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I now have several devices that start the monthly mdadm scheduled check.  I can let them all run monthly, stagger the checks, or disable them completely.  I had the misfortune of several disks turning up bad this month causing a few arrays to run in a degraded state for many hours and I'm not sure what the idea setup is for this.  Conversation regarding this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 1):

You can set mdadm to send you email on degrading events.  Simply have sendmail installed and running, and set this line in `/etc/mdadm.conf`:

```
MAILADDR address@somedomain.com
```

Comment: On Debian Jessie the config file is located at /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf by default.